# Problems with creating custom UserControl in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio-2013, user-controls

I have SP2010 project and want to create a custom menu using custom UserControl (I have a working example in another project but don't have access to a developer who made it).

I found a few guides like [this](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/04/how-to-create-user-control-in-sharepoint2010.html). It says that after deploying it will create a new folder with my control in 14 hive's Control templates folder.

The problem is that there is no folder created after deploying. So, after further steps like register new control and adding it on master page I got an error "File not found.", because, yes, there is no file over there.

So where did I make a mistake?

Comment: How you are deploying the solution? using visual studio?

Comment: @AakashMorya yes

Comment: If possible just share the snaps of your solution structure and the code which you are using to register the UserControl..

Comment: @AakashMorya https://unsee.cc/ratezipo/